# If $d$ is a metric, is $d(x,\;\cdot\;)$ continuous from above?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in E$ and $$d(x,B):=\inf_{y\in B}d(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }B\subseteq E.$$

> Let $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be nonincreasing and $B:=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Are we able to show that $d(x,B_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}d(x,B)$?

Since $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nonincreasing, we clearly obtain $$d(x,B_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}d(x,B_n)\in[0,\infty]\tag1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B_n=\{0\}\cup (1,1+\frac 1 n)$. Then $B_n$ decreases to $B=\{0\}$. $d(2,B_n) \to 1$ whreas $d(2,B)=2$.

Comment: Can we at least show that there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $d(x,B_n)\ge\frac{d(x,B)}2$ for all $n\ge n_0$?

Comment: No. $d(1.5, B)=1.5$ and $d(1.5,B_n) \to 0.5$ in my example. @0xbadf00d

Comment: It seems like you're obviously right. Am I missing something or isn't the proof on page 9 in [this paper](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/177/SC-95-11.pdf) wrong then? It seems like this is precisely used to obtain $d(f^{-1}(y),Q_k)>\delta/2$ for all $k>N$.

Comment: Maybe it's crucial to assume that the $B_n$ are closed. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4054799/47771.

Comment: Closed is also not enough. But if $B_n$'s are compact and they decrease to $B$ then $d(x,B_n) \to d(x,B)$. @0xbadf00d

Comment: Why is that? How do we prove this claim?