# If $B_n$ is compact and $B_n\subseteq B_{n+1}$, is there a $n_0$ with $d(x,B_n)\ge d(x,\bigcap_nB_n)/2$ for all $n\ge n_0$?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in E$ and $$d(x,B):=\inf_{y\in B}d(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }B\subseteq E.$$

> Let $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be nonincreasing and $B:=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$. It seems like that in the proof on page 9 in [this paper](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/177/SC-95-11.pdf), it s claimed that if $x\not\in B$ (hence $\delta:=d(x,B)>0$), there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $d(x,B_n)\ge\frac{d(x,B)}2$ for all $n\ge n_0$.
>
> As the example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4054690/47771) shows, this is not true in general. In the paper, every $B_n$ (hence $B$) is compact, but I don't see how this makes any difference. So, is there anything else I'm missing or is the proof in the paper wrong?

Comment: In the link $B_n$ are not compact. Thus, those do not provide a counterexample. Here compactness is necessary, while in the link there is no reference to compactness.

Comment: @Crostul Could you elaborate on how compactness yields the claim?

Comment: Here is a sketch of the proof: Compactness has many properties: firstly you can show that $$d(x, B_n) = d(x, b_n)$$ for some $b_n \in B_n$ (this is not true if $B_n$ is not compact). Then $\{ b_n \}_n$ is a sequence of points in $B_1$ which is compact: hence you can find a convergent subsequence $b_{n_k} \to b \in B$. Then you can show that $$d(x,B) = d(x,b)$$ and that $$\lim_n d(x,b_n) = d(x,b)$$ This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $b_n \in B_n$ such that $d(x,B_n)+\frac 1 n >d(x,b_n)$ $\, \, (1)$. There is  a subsequence $(b_{n_k})$ of $(b_n)$ converging to some $b$. Let $N \geq 1$.  Since $b_{n_k} \in B_{n_k} \subseteq B_N$ for all $k$ sufficiently large it follows that $b \in B_N$. This is true for all $N$, so $x \in B$. Now $d(x,B) \leq d(x,b)=\lim d(x,b_{n_k})\leq \lim  d(x,B_n)$ by (1).  Of course, $d(x,B_n) \leq d(x,B)$ for all $n$. Conclusion: $d(x,B_n) \to d(x,B)$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The continuity of $d(x,\;\cdot\;)$ should even yield that we can choose $b_n$ s.t. $d(x,b_n)=d(x,b_n)$, right?

Comment: You wrote $\lim d(x,b_{n_k})\leq \lim  d(x,B_n)$, but shouldn't it be $\lim d(x,b_{n_k})\leq \lim  d(x,B_{n_k})$ instead? Now the conclusion would "only" be $d(x,B_{n_k}\to d(x,B)$, i.e. that there is a subsequence s.t. the convergence holds. But by monotonicity this is clearly enough.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I am using the fact that $d(x,B_n)$ is an increasing sequence, so the limitof any subsequence is same as the limit of the whole sequnce.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You are right about $d(x,b_n)=d(x,B_n)$.

Comment: Everything I've asked so far boils down to the goal of understanding why the claim in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4055051/47771) holds true. I highly doubt that the result is actually true. Could you please take a look?